# What is this いけ

Tags: grammar

太郎くんはお化けの話を聞いたあと、夜一人でトイレに**行け**なくなりました。

The problem in this sentence is the predicative. 
なくなりました should literally translate into "became weeping". 
But I'm thoroughly clueless about this いけ before that. 
I can't even say what form this shall represent.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

泣く【なく】 (to weep) is not relevant.

> 太郎くんはトイレに行けなくなりました。
>   Taro became unable to go to the toilet.

- 行く: "to go"
- 行ける: "to be able to go" ([potential form](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/learn/grammar/potential) of 行く)
- 行けない: "not to be able to go", "to be unable to go" (negative potential form)
- 行けなく: (continuative/adverbial form of 行けない, which connects to ～なる)
- ～なる: "to become ～" (see [Using 「なる」 with i-adjectives](http://www.guidetojapanese.org/surunaru.html#part3))